# How to adjust spacing or margin for secondary Y axis on ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, margin, axis

I am working on a ggplot in R with the following code:

```
s=40
ggplot(data = NULL) +
  geom_line(data = stk, aes(x = date, y = price)) +
  geom_line(data = gdp, aes(x = year, y = gdp1*s)) +
  scale_y_continuous("Index of Total Stock Price",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~. /s, name = "Real GDP (trillions of USD in 2012)"),
                     limits = c(0, 100)) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq(from = as.Date("1900-01-01"),
                            to = as.Date("1945-01-01"),
                            by = "5 years"),
               labels=date_format("%Y")) +
  xlab(element_blank())
```

And this output:

[image]

The problem is that the text and ticks in the secondary axis look very cramped up. How can I make the space between the ticks and the axis label be the same for both y axis labels? Thanks.

EDIT:

Here is reproducible data:

```
set.seed(1000)
df1 <- data.frame(y1=rnorm(100, 0, 1),
                  x=seq(1, 100, 1))
df2 <- data.frame(y2=rnorm(100, 0, 1),
                  x=seq(1, 100, 1))
ggplot(data = NULL) +
  geom_line(data = df1, aes(x = x, y = y1)) +
  geom_line(data = df2, aes(x = x, y = y2*2)) +
  scale_y_continuous("Label of Primary Y Axis",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~. *2, name = "Label of Secondary Y Axis"))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you update a reproducible sample? BTW, you can try adding, +  theme(axis.title.y= element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 10, b = 0, l = 0))) + 
  theme(axis.title.y.right = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 10)))

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you should consider an alternative presentation of this data: https://blog.datawrapper.de/dualaxis/

Comment: Just using the second part of that, `theme(axis.title.y.right = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 10))`, worked very well. The first part simply added space to the primary y axis, so I didn't put it. It's weird why the primary label seems predetermined to have more space, but this is a great fix, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, using the second part of that,

```
theme(axis.title.y.right = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 10))
```

worked for me.